# Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen »Sinnes-« und »Sinnen-«

Tags: meaning, difference, etymology

Im Sprachgebrauch hat sich der Begriff »Sinne**s**wandel« etabliert, doch kürzlich bin ich über das Wort »Sinne**n**wandel« gestolpert.
Grimm kennt keines von beiden, dafür aber »Sinne**s**änderung« und »Sinne**s**wechsel«.

Zunächst dachte ich, »Sinnenwandel« sei eine Alternative zu »Sinneswandel«, doch die Bedeutung stimmt nicht mit dem Kontext überein:
Der Titel eines Buches von Michael Giesecke lautet *Sinnenwandel, Sprachwandel, Kulturwandel: Studien zur Vorgeschichte der Informationsgesellschaft*.
Darin beschreibt der Autor die Verschiebung der Priorität der Sinne in der Gesellschaft (von einem vergleichsweise ausgeglichenen Verhältnis in vorschriftlichen Gesellschaften hin zu einer starken Betonung des Visuellen seit der Verbreitung der Schrift).
Der Sinnenwandel im Titel bezieht sich also konkret auf die Sinne.

Der Sinne**s**wandel kommt etymologisch zwar auch von den Sinnen, doch lässt er sich im heutigen Sprachgebrauch mit Meinungswechsel gleichsetzen, während *Sinn* diese Bedeutung nur noch in festen Wendungen (z. B. »Er handelte in ihrem Sinne«) erhält.

---

Bei Grimm finden sich zahlreiche Wörter, die mit *Sinnes-* beginnen (Auswahl):

- Sinnesänderung
- Sinnesfreiheit
- Sinneskraft
- Sinnesleer

Ebenfalls stehen dort viele Wörter, die mit *Sinnen-* anfangen (Auswahl):

- Sinnenblind
- Sinnenhain
- Sinnenlust
- Sinnenschärfe

Diese Auswahl spiegelt nicht den gesamten Umfang wider: Man sollte sich selbst im [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS29400#XGS29400) ein Bild machen.

---

Es scheint mir (tendenziell; nicht als feste Regel), als käme *Sinnes-* eher in Wörtern vor, die sich auf die Gesinnung (Einstellung, Meinung, Zugehörigkeit, Streben) beziehen, während *Sinnen-* sich häufiger auf die Sinne (hören, sehen…) bezieht.

Lässt sich diese These halten?
Und wie ist der unterschiedliche Gebrauch derselben Wurzel (Sinn) grammatisch oder etymologisch zu begründen?

Comment: Ich denke, das hat eher damit zu tun, dass der *Sinneswandel* (im Sinne [sic] von "Ich ändere meine Meinung") schon belegt war, und der Autor *Sinnenwandel* gewählt hat, um "Ich ändere meine Wahrnehmung" auszudrücken (Ich glaube, ich hätte lieber "Veränderung der Wahrnehmung" genommen, aber das hat wohl nicht aufs Titelblatt gepasst). Eine Verallgemeinerung scheint mir daraus nicht möglich. (*Sinnwandel* wäre noch möglich gewesen, darunter stelle ich mir aber wieder was anderes vor)

Comment: @tofro Ich verstehe, was du meinst, aber das war ja auch nur der Aufhänger für die Überlegung, die sich aus den leicht unterschiedlichen Bedeutungsfeldern der Wörter, die mit Sinnen- und mit Sinnes- beginnen (wie sie bei Grimm stehen), ergibt.

Comment: übrigens würde ich alle deine "Sinnen-"-Beispiele unter *archaisch* oder zumindestens *antiquiert* einordnen. Diese Verwendung scheint es zunehmend weniger zu geben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zuerst: Ich kann außer dem speziellen Buchtitel und Bezügen darauf keine Verwendung von "Sinnenwandel" im Internet finden. Das Wort scheint in dieser Bedeutung relativ einzigartig zu sein. Man kann allerdings Verwendungen desselben Wortes mit offensichtlich gleicher Bedeutung wie "Sinneswandel" ausmachen, z.B. [hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=2Y0hAAAAQBAJ&pg=RA3-PA30&dq=%22sinnenwandel%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1me2Tu-TbAhXJWiwKHTKzDy0Q6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%22sinnenwandel%22&f=false).

Der Autor des Buches scheint hier ein Opfer der Bedeutungsüberschneidung von *Sinn*

1. Wahrnehmung (sehen, hören, fühlen) und
2. Verarbeitung ("bei Sinnen" sein, "sinnen" (nachdenken)) und
3. Grund, Hintergrund, Absicht ("Er hatte im Sinn, ... zu machen")

Dieser Wortstamm ist traditionell schon mit so vielen Bedeutungen belegt, das es schwierig ist, neue Zusammensetzungen zu finden, die genau wiedergeben, was gemeint ist. Hier muss man sich zuerst vergegenwärtigen, was denn eine Zusammensetzung im Deutschen genau bedeutet - Im allgemeinen Wird ein Genitivzusammenhang

> Sinneswandel = Wandel des Sinnes

unterstellt. Allerdings ist auch der Genitiv schon mehrdeutig, denn er kann im Deutschen mindestens 7 Bedeutungen tragen, die teilweise auch noch vollkommen gegensätzlich (*objectivus/subjectivus*) sein können.

Darüberhinaus: Dem verwendeten Fugenlaut ("s" oder "n") eine Bedeutung unterstellen zu wollen, erscheint mir risikoreich - Ich glaube, die gibt es nicht. Ich finde keinen solchen Zusammenhang in anderen Komposita, allerhöchstens, dass sich Singular und Plural unterscheiden ("Bankpleite" <> "Bankenpleite").

Was der Autor sich wohl gedacht hat, scheint zu sein, dass "Sinne" im Plural  hauptsächlich die Wahrnehmung betreffen ("seine 5 Sinne beinander haben", "im Reich der Sinne"). Mir fällt grade keine Verwendung von "Sinn" im Plural ein, die anderen beiden Bedeutungen berühren würde.  Nur ist der Plural eben nicht "Sinnen". Eine Abgrenzung wäre also möglich gewesen, indem er

> Sinnewandel

als Begriff genommen hätte.

Daraus, dass Zusammensetzungen im Deutschen einen (mehrdeutigen) Genitivzusammenhang tragen, denke ich, kann man ableiten, dass diese Mehrdeutigkeit zusammen mit der zusätzlichen Mehrdeutigkeit des Grundbegriffs in die Zusammensetzung übernommen wird. Und genauswenig, wie es ohne Kontext eine Regel gibt, welche Bedeutung des Genitivs gerade gemeint ist, kann man das dann eben bei der Zusammensetzung sagen. Ohne Kontext kann man auch nicht bestimmen, welche Bedeutung von "Sinn" denn jetzt gemeint ist.

Nein, ich glaube den von dir vermuteten Zusammenhang gibt es nicht. "Sinn" ist immer mehrdeutig und Komposita sind zusätzlich auch noch mehrdeutig.

In einer Fachpublikation wie die, auf die du dich beziehst, kann (darf) man mit einer Begriffsdefinition und einer durchgehenden Verwendung arbeiten. In der Alltagssprache funktioniert das allerdings nicht.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Natürlich sind s und n Fugenlaute, aber den Bedeutungsunterschied allgemein auf diese Laute zu übertragen ist mir gar nicht eingefallen, ich hatte eher an eine sprachliche Auseinanderentwicklung von Sinnes und Sinnen gedacht (ohne dafür eine ordentliche Begründung zu haben).